# Running Jenkins on Tomcat Fail applicaton at context path /jenkins could not be started

Tags: jenkins, tomcat7

For a few days I am trying to set Jenkins on Tomcat7 without any result... I read many tutorials and I could not find any help...

I set a virtual system on VirtualBox -> Ubuntu 12.04.04

Using apt-get I installed tomcat7, and then Jenkins.
While using them separately by usingcommad `sudo service tomcat7 start` or `sudo service jenkins start` both services starts and are visable on my localhost.

However, when I copied jenkins.war to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps I cannot run it via tomcat.
I have set JENKINS_HOME as /var/lib/jenkins.
In the folder /usr/share/tomcat7 i run these commands: `sudo mkdir .jenkins | sudo chown tomcat7:nogroup .jenkins`
And from localhost:8080/manager jenkins is viable:
 [image]

When I try `localhost:8080/jenkins` as tutorials says I get en error message: [image]

I really have no idea what am I doing wrong...
What else may I try to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Please check Java compatibility version with the "Jenkins.war" file. I used Java 8 for Jenkins version 2.107.1.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to shutdown restart the tomcat server. As it should be able to read the .war file. Hence, you will go through additional setup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the version of your `jenkins.war` file
2. Check the compatibe java version for hat jenkins version in web
3. Download that version of java and define system environment variables path for `JAVA_HOME`
4. Open "Monitor tomcat" in that JAVA define the path of `jvm.dll`
   example `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16\bin\server\jvm.dll`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This picture shows how to run in windows:

[image: screenshot of solution]

Comment: Please add a textual description of the solution you propose.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while deploying jenkins in tomcat in window11
while using tomcat verion 10.1.5

In trying to resolve

i installed apache tomcat 9.0.72
link for tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi

and

jenkins war file 2.375.3
link for jenkins war file : https://www.jenkins.io/download/

and JDK version 17 as jenkins works with java JDK version 17

and now its working perfectly fine

hope it will help you

Answer (score -1):

Please check your JRE path, as I face a similar issue where JRE_HOME was incorrectly set

> JRE_HOME=/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_21,

It started working when I correct it to latest JRE version

> JRE_HOME=/usr/jdk/jdk1.7.0_09/jre.